# PDF form parsing OR submit PDF and open browser

Tags: php, forms, parsing, pdf, browser

I have searched all over and can not find a solution.  I am using PHP and the TCPDF library to dynamically create a simple form like so:

```
    function getPDF() {
    // create new PDF document
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('EnTax');
    $pdf->SetTitle('SRED Score');
    $pdf->SetSubject('SRED Score Application');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

    // set default header data
    $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);

    // set header and footer fonts
    $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
    $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

    // set default monospaced font
    $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

    // set margins
    $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
    $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
    $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

    // set auto page breaks
    $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

    // set image scale factor
    $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

    // IMPORTANT: disable font subsetting to allow users editing the document
    $pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);

    // set font
    $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 10, '', false);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $html = '';
    $html .= '<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/index.php?method=submit_form">';
    $html .= '<label for="question1" class="control-label">Question 1</label><textarea id="question1" name="question1" style="width:100%;height:100px;" class="ccm-input-textarea form-control">'.$this->post('question1').'</textarea>';
    $html .= '<input type="submit" class="btn ccm-input-submit btn-default" id="getpdf" name="getpdf" value="Launch Website"></form>';
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
    $pdf->Ln(6);
    $pdf->Output('sred_score.pdf', 'D');        
}
```

This works fine when using Adobe Acrobat but when I submit the form embedded in the PDF file, it would be ideal if this opened up a browser with the URL.  Sadly it opens another Adobe Acrobat with the server page - which of course looks horrible.  Is there a magic way to tell Acrobat that I really want to open a browser?  ...and can I do this using TCPDF?

---OR----

...I have also tried to figure out how to get the value from the form fields using the PHP PDFParser library but while I can get the static test text, I can't seem to access the form.  Is this at all possible using TCPDF or PDFParser?  My example parsing code looks like so:

```
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $pdf = $parser->parseFile($file);
    $pages  = $pdf->getPages();

    // Loop over each page to extract text.
    $out = '';
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $out .= $page->getText() . '<br/>';
        foreach($page->getXObjects() as $o) {
            $out .= 'OBJ: '.$o->getText().'<br/>';
        }
    }
    echo $out;
```

Comment: just set the for action url to your actual site

Comment: I'm using fpdf to create pdf's and am not really sure, but I guess it might be quite equal. In your last line $pdf->Output('sred_score.pdf', 'D'); the D usually tells pdf where you want the result to be shown. There shall be a option for inline opening, with fpdf it's 'I'. Sorry if it's wrong, but might be an idea.

Comment: @Dagon : Do you mean the action URL for the HTML form tag?  At the moment it is actually localhost.  Is there a PDF specific action that can be set?

Comment: @michael : Thanks, but I'm not trying to display the PDF inline - the file download to my computer which is what I want.  When viewing it with Adobe Acrobat, I want Acrobat to open a browser with the URL specified by the HTML form tag URL.  I'm ultimately trying to take the form results and pre-populate a web form.